# How to associate two models in two ways: many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In a political analysis application using Rails 3.2.15, I have a Candidate model and a District model. Here's the breakdown of the relationships I'm trying to model:

1. Candidates belong to Districts, since they run for office in a particular District.
2. One or more Candidates can also be incumbent in their district.
3. One incumbent is the "Primary Incumbent" for the District.

I'm thinking of it this way:

```
class District
  has_many :candidates
  has_many :candidates, :through => :incumbencies
end

class Candidate
  belongs_to: District
end

class Incumbency
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :candidate
  # This model has a boolean attribute :is_primary to distinguish primary incumbencies
end
```

Is this the right approach, or will I run into problems? Thanks for any help.

*Edit:*

Here's an example to clarify:

#### In District 1

- Candidate 1 is primary incumbent
- Candidate 2 is incumbent
- Candidate 3 is a candidate
- Candidate 4 is a candidate

#### In District 2

- Candidate 5 is a candidate
- Candidate 6 is a candidate

#### In District 3

- Candidate 7 is primary incumbent
- Candidate 8 is a candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks to be in order, but I believe there may be a problem that Incumbencies belongs_to :candidates but Candidates do not have any incumbencies.  I think it might work a bit better if you have:

```
class District
  has_many :candidates
  has_many :incumbencies, :through => :candidates
end

class Candidate
  belongs_to :district
  has_one :incumbency
end

class Incumbency
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :candidate
  # This model has a boolean attribute :is_primary to distinguish primary incumbencies
end
```

I may be understanding your relationships incorrectly but it seems a candidate can either have or not have a single incumbency, and the district has many candidates, some of which are incumbancies.

Comment: Thanks! I just added a few examples to clarify the cases. Does this code describe them?

Comment: I believe so, all of your examples should fit into this code structure.  The only tricky part will be when you try to pull up the primary incumbent for a given district, but as long as you set up your queries correctly, everything should be fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by the tricky part? I think you mean finding which incumbencies on a district have is_primary set to true. Would I be able to do something like my_district.incumbencies.where("is_primary == true")?

Comment: Queries aren't my strong suit, so that's probably why I think it's tricky.  This is how I would attempt it but I can't say for sure if it's correct. `my_district.joins(:incumbencies).where("incumbencies.is_primary ?", true)`